# How to tell the GCC compiler that code should be generated serial, i.e., without jumps

Tags: c, gcc, llvm, llvm-gcc

> How to tell the GCC compiler that code should be generated serial, i.e., without jumps.

I'm working on a project that embeds inline assembly into a C source code (or LLVM IR).

My implementation depends on code between the inline assembly to be written into  the executable as-is.

More formally, suppose I have the soure code (C or LLVM IR):

```
.label_start: (inserted as inline assembly)
inline_assembly0
source_code0
source_code1
inline_assembly1
...
.label_end: (inserted as inline assembly)
...
```

Now, this should not be compiled as:

```
.jmp_target:
source_code1
inline_assembly1
...
.label_end: (inserted as inline assembly)
...

.label_start: (inserted as inline assembly)
inline_assembly0
source_code0
jmp jmp_target
```

I.e. code should stay between labels without jumps reordering `.label_start` and `.label_end`.

Is there any way of telling GCC that everything between two inline assembly labels should stay "intact" without being reordered? My implementation depends on this.

Comment: Does this code segment happen to be inside a loop?

Comment: Why do you need this? In any case do you have a CPU that doesn't perorm out-of-order execution.

Comment: In general, the code could be inside a loop @BenVoigt.

Comment: Because I compute a checksum over the range determined by the two labels at runtime to tamper proof an application @PaulFloyd.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. If you want a specific machine code sequence, use assembly language. But first you should understand **why** you want it and use C in the first place, **unless you can proof C is not sufficient**.

Comment: @Olaf  - I cannot do that. I'm modifying existing source code I may not have written myself programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) has a few words on this (emphasis added).

> Note that the compiler can move even volatile `asm` instructions relative to other code, including across jump instructions. For example, on many targets there is a system register that controls the rounding mode of floating-point operations. Setting it with a volatile `asm`, as in the following PowerPC example, does not work reliably.
>
> ```
> asm volatile("mtfsf 255, %0" : : "f" (fpenv));
> sum = x + y;
> ```
>
> The compiler may move the addition back before the volatile `asm`. **To make it work as expected, add an artificial dependency to the `asm` by referencing a variable in the subsequent code**, for example:
>
> ```
> asm volatile("mtfsf 255,%1" : "=X" (sum) : "f" (fpenv));
> sum = x + y;
> ```

Basically, you need a “dummy use” to prevent reordering.

We also use this sort of thing in Mono to extend the liveness of a reference in low-level GC code, ensuring it won’t be prematurely freed if the GC interrupts a routine:

```
static inline void dummy_use (void *v)
    __asm__ volatile ("" : "=r"(v) : "r"(v));
}
```

Comment: This deals with order of execution, but the question is discussing memory layout

Comment: Thanks, this was very informative! But does it ensure memory layout?

Comment: @Shuzheng: Not really, as Ben Voigt says, it only lets you ensure that the code executes in a certain order. For example, a cold branch might still be moved out of line. In general I guess you need to do something like `#pragma GCC push_options`, `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")`, …, `#pragma GCC pop_options` to locally disable all optimisations. (`-fno-reorder-blocks` might be enough.) You could also use inline assembly for everything in these blocks, if that’s feasible for you.

Comment: @JonPurdy - it isn't, because some code between labels may be LLVM IR or C. So, I would need to convert source to inline assembly. Also, inline assembly for everything may still be reordered, right? (Using jumps)

Answer (score 1):

try to disable optimization, gcc -O0 source.c